# Python - Automate code involving suffix

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to automate this portion of code in python (code shown for 2 polygons, I am trying to do the same for 10 000 polygons). Any ideas on how to implement this using `for` loop or whichever fastest way you recommend.

```
### Polygon 1 
def checkPolygon1(row):
    point = Point((row['X']), (row['Y']))
    return polygon1.contains(point)

#Apply fn to each row of dataframe (datacopy)
datacopy.apply(checkPolygon1, axis=1)

#Create new variable InPolygon1 in data if X, Y in shapely file 
datacopy['InPolygon1'] = datacopy.apply(checkPolygon1, axis=1)



### Polygon 2
def checkPolygon2(row):
    point = Point((row['X']), (row['Y']))
    return polygon2.contains(point)

datacopy.apply(checkPolygon2, axis=1)
#Create new variable InPolygon2 in data if X, Y in shapely file 
datacopy['InPolygon2'] = datacopy.apply(checkPolygon2, axis=1)
```

Comment: Your description is missing the _purpose_ of the code. You say the code does something "for two polygons", but you didn't say what this "something" is.

Answer (score 2):

Both functions `checkPolygon1` and `checkPolygon2` perform essentially the same actions and only differ in specific *polygon* instance. 
That's an appropriate case for [*Parameterize Function*](https://refactoring.com/catalog/parameterizeFunction.html) refactoring technique where *polygon* instance can serve as a *factor*.

Define a unified function **`point_in_polygon`** (don't forget about Python naming conventions):

```
def point_in_polygon(row, polygon):
    return polygon.contains(Point(row['X'], row['Y']))
```

Then, assuming that you already have a *list* or *generator* of polygons `polygons`:

```
for i, polygon in enumerate(polygons, 1):
    datacopy[f'InPolygon{i}'] = datacopy.apply(point_in_polygon, axis=1, polygon=polygon)
```